# How can I fetch() more than 1MB on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

Google App Engine limits `urlfetch.fetch()` responses to [1MB](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits). Is there any workaround of this (switching to paid version maybe)?

I'm using Python and if it's possible to provide an example that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the brand new [SDK 1.4.0](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/0f90ef8dda3b8400) you can download 32MByte; <strike>keep in mind that you still have the 10 seconds Deadline limit though ;-) .</strike> deadline can be up to a maximum of 60 seconds for request handlers and 10 minutes for tasks queue and cron job handlers.

> URLFetch allowed response size has
>   been increased, up to 32 MB. Request
>   size is still limited to 1 MB.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot fetch more than 1MB per URL fetch (even if you enable billing).  However, you might be able to fetch portions of the target URL using the [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header and then combine these pieces.  This might even be faster since you could fetch each 1MB chunk simultaneously (using [asynchronous fetches](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html)).

Comment: +1 Great answer. Do you have any info on support for `Content-Range` on various public services like Flickr, DropBox, etc..?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Range` (not `Content-Range`).  And yes, both Flickr and DropBox support it.  I'm sure many others do too.

Comment: how can fetch only the headers to get at least the size of it. I tried to put the `allow_truncated=True` but on a really big file from Dropbox didn't work. With a smaller one I got a chunk of 1MB..

Comment: Ok I got only the header via the `method='HEAD'` but there is nothing there to indicate the size :( is there another way of setting all the ranges? Because I need to know the total size upfront.. right?

Comment: The server should set the `Content-Length` header whenever possible.  If you don't know the size up front, then I suppose you could still try fetching 1MB chunks until you receive a response back which contains less data the maximum amount (assumedly because you hit the end of the content).