# "Timeout while fetching" URLFetch GAE/J

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using the XMLReader to simply read a feed like below.

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection(); 
XmlReader reader = new XmlReader(urlConnection);
```

When this is called I receive within 5 seconds an IOException "Timeout 
while fetching". So I tried to set the timeouts to the max. (10 sec) but still no luck and still an IOExeption in 5 sec.

```
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
```

(the max is stated in documentation: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html)

Seems that the size of the feed is too large. When I call a smaller feed 
it works properly. Is there any workaround or solution for this? I need to be able to call larger feeds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `setReadTimeout` method that sets the read deadline:

```
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000); //10 Sec
```

You should be able to download larger feeds in 10 seconds.
If you still have problem, try to fiddle with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109255/how-can-i-fetch-more-than-1mb-on-google-app-engine/4109355#4109355) different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried it, unfortunately still the same Exception. It seems there is totally no response within the 5 seconds.

Comment: @Ben sounds odd to me; how many seconds does it take to get this feed via browser for example?

Comment: It takes about 10 sec. in the browser (FireFox/Chrome/IE)

Comment: @Ben wow, that's a fat feed. If the server supports "range requests" you could try to asynch fetch smaller chunks of feed; I don't know if it does fit for this kind of data though.

Comment: I'll try, thanks. Although, I still think it's strange that the timeout time is not influenced by the setConnectionTimeout or setReadTimeout.

Comment: @Ben wait, setReadTimeout(10000) sets the deadline to the max (10sec) and, as you said, feed takes 10 seconds even from the browser; it sounds reasonable that GAE raises a Deadline exception on urlfetch.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is:

If no data is available for the read timeout period, exception can be thrown. From [the doc of Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)

> A SocketTimeoutException can be thrown when reading from the returned input stream if the read timeout expires before data is available for read.

By the way, `ReadTimeout` is different with `ConnectTimeout`, the read timeout is the timeout to get data from the host, see [different connection timeout and read timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069382/what-is-the-difference-between-connection-and-read-timeout-for-sockets)

So as @systempuntoout answer, need to set read timeout.